# How to automatically run a command after saving a file

Tags: vim

I want vim to run g++ after saving a `.cpp` file to compile it. How can I achieve this? I know how to map an external command to keys, but I want to know how to map a command to another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do that. Most of the time we save files that are not fully compilable (because we want to update tags database, make sure the file is saved before going home). Moreover most of the projects are not made of single files.

But anyway. You are looking for `BufWritePost` autocommands. For instance,

```
aug AutoCompileCppFiles
    au!
    au BufWritePost *.cpp,*.c make 
aug END
```

BTW, `:make` shall do the work as it'll call gnumake on most systems, and gnumake already knows how to compile single isolated files. If you want to parametrize the compilation, just set $LDFLAGS and $CXXFLAGS ; e.g.:

```
:let $CXXFLAGS='-std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic'
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `:autocmd` for that. After a `:write`, the `BufWritePost` event is fired. See `:h autocmd-events` for what's available.

```
:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> !g++ %
```

The `%` represents the current file (that is written).

A better alternative might be to invoke `:make` instead; this can also handle more than single file compiles.

To install that for *all* C++ files, you could just replace `<buffer>` with `*.cpp`, but then you're duplication the *filetype detection* built into Vim. Better put the above `:autocmd` into e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp_autocompile.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`. Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType cpp autocmd BufWritePost...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.